# Method with a parameter that accepts Different types of Enum values

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics

I have a method that accepts Enum values as parameter, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1558878/4466640) is my reference. However I cant seem to make it work.

**Enums**

```
Public Enum FieldTypes
    db_Alpha = 0
    db_Memo = 1
    db_Numeric = 2
End Enum

Public Enum SubTypes
    st_None = 0
    st_Phone = 35
    st_Percentage = 37
    st_Address = 63
    st_Link = 66
End Enum
```

**Method**

```
Public Sub Foo(Of T)(ByVal Param1 As String, ByVal EnumParam As T)
     Dim param As Type = GetType(T)
     If param.IsEnum Then
        Dim x = param.GetEnumValues()
     End If
     'Running some codes here
End Sub
```

**Main**

```
Public Sub Test()
    Foo("TestName",FieldTypes.db_Memo)
End Sub
```

Im getting all the values of the type of Enum that was passed as a parameter. 
I would want to reduce Method overloading and learn about generics here. Accepting C# and VB.net suggestions.

1. How could I get the value of of the Enum item passed?
2. How can I restrict this, that only the two types of Enum written is accepted?

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378801/get-the-integer-value-of-an-enumeration-which-is-a-generic

Comment: 1) Cast to integer 2) You can't with generics. You could create 2 overloaded methods.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  You start off with a generic type for an argument type that presumably must be derived from [System.Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx). This is no place for a generic type; make the argument type a `System.Enum` and then you have limited the possibilities substantially.  However, you finish up the question with the request of limiting the method signature to only two enum types.  All of this to avoid writing two overloads for the method that avoids all the type determining code and gives you strong intellisense support.

Comment: @TnTinMn Yes generic but limiting 2 inputs, thank you for the insight on this. Im still studying this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an `Enum` is always a value type you can restrict your function "Foo" to only accept value types.

```
Public Sub Foo(Of T As Structure)(ByVal Param1 As String, ByVal EnumParam As T)
```

You could also restrict your generic function to only accept reference types

```
Public Sub Test(Of T As Class)(ByVal param As T)
```

or only accept types that implement a specific interface

```
Public Sub Test(Of T As IDispose)(ByVal param As T)
```

You can even concatenate those conditions

```
Public Sub Test(Of T As Class, IDispose, IEnumerable)(ByVal param As T)
```

Inside your function "Foo" you can check, that T is of the correct type like this:

```
If Not GetType(T).Equals(GetType(FieldTypes)) AndAlso _
   Not GetType(T).Equals(GetType(SubTypes)) Then
    Throw New Exception("Enum type not supported")
End If
```

To get the numeric value of "EnumParam" you can convert it to `Integer` or whatever else numeric type your enumeration is based on:

```
Dim x As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(EnumParam)
```

Comment: Thank You! I'll tinker with this solution.